# Flutter api calls oauth_signature HMAC-SHA1 generation

Tags: flutter, api, dart, oauth, hmacsha1

I am trying to make an API call to my server everything works properly on postman but I can't seem to get it going on Flutter

```
                      String oauthConsumer ='oauth_consumer_key=[MyKey]';
                      String oauthNonce =
                          'oauth_nonce=${Random().nextInt(4294967296).toString()}';
                      String oauthCallback =
                          'oauth_callback=[MyCallback address]';
                      String oauthVersion = 'oauth_version=1.0';
                      String oauthTime =
                          'oauth_timestamp=${(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000).toString()}';
                      String oauthMethod = 'oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1';

                      var oauthList = [
                        oauthCallback,
                        oauthConsumer,
                        oauthNonce,
                        oauthMethod,
                        oauthTime,
                        oauthVersion
                      ];
                      oauthList.sort();
                      String oauthSig = //[I need a method to create this properly]

                      var request = http.Request('POST', Uri.parse([My URL]));
                      http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

                      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                        print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
                      }
```

Like I mention postman does return the token and the token secret but trying on Flutter returns the `Authentication Required`  error

Picture of the Postman request body

[image]

On the Authorization tab just filled in the `Consumer Key` and the `Consumer Secret` the headers where left untouched and default like this:

[image]

Comment: You are making a POST request but don't appear to be including any body with it. Update the question with a screenshot of the working postman request.

Comment: You've posted a postman screenshot but don't show the request headers or body (or is it empty?) Have you added other headers, etc in the headers or authorization tabs?

Comment: @RichardHeap The headers are default, the body is indeed empty and the only thing I added was to the Authentication tab, both Consumer Key and Secret, thank you!

Comment: So, you need to include those auth values in Flutter. - post a redacted screenshot of the auth tab.

Comment: @RichardHeap that's how the auth tab looks on postman, on regards to flutter how am I supposed to include them?

Comment: For the base string and key as described here: https://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Signing.html and calculate the hmac using https://pub.dev/packages/crypto . Add that to the parameters (which for a POST will be a map). Finally use `http.post(url, body: theMapOfParameters, headers: theMapOfHeaders)` - you will need to add at least one header with `Authorization` -> `OAuth...`